# Evaluar la existencia del tipo de extensiones dentro de un ArrayList

Tags: java

necesito evaluar el contenido de archivos de un `ArrayList<String>` llamado **arrayArchivos**, el cual contiene los archivos levantados por extensión de una direccion especifica, lo cual hago para levantar dichas extensiones.

```
     public void buscarArchivo(File ruta) {
            //        Creo el vector que contendra todos los archivos de una ruta especificada.
                    File[] archivo = ruta.listFiles();
            //        Evaluo si la carpeta especificada contiene archivos.
                    if (archivo != null) {
            //            Recorro el vector el cual tiene almacenado la ruta del archivo a buscar.
                        for (int i = 0; i < archivo.length; i++) {
                            File Arc = archivo[i];
            //                Evaluo si el archivo o la ruta es una carpeta.
                            if (archivo[i].isDirectory()) {
            //                    Le paso la nueva ruta de la carpeta si se cambia la ruta e busca nuevamente.
                                buscarArchivo(archivo[i]);
                            } else {
            //                    Evaluo el tipo de extencion. 
                                if (archivo[i].getName().endsWith(".pnd") || archivo[i].getName().endsWith(".ana") || archivo[i].getName().endsWith(".cnf")) {
                                    contador++;
                                    arrayArchivos.add(archivo[i].getName());
                                    System.out.println("Lo que hay en el array es: " + arrayArchivos);

                                    >>>Aquí necesitaría preguntar si existen archivos en el arraylist con las 3 extensiones que levanto de la carpeta.
                                    Los cuales son .pnd .ana .cnf<<<
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

- Necesito saber si dentro del arraylist existen las 3 extensiones, independientemente del num de archivos que encuentre, si existen las tres extensiones que no haga nada.
- Puede haber hasta 2 archivos con el mismo nombre pero con distinta extensión por ej: (**juan.pnd** y **juan.ana**) o (**juan.pnd** y **juan.cnf**) en ese caso que no haga nada.
- También pueden existir solo dos extensiones por ej: **pedro.cnf** y **pablo.ana**
- También puede existir 1 sola extensión por ej: El **.ana** solo o el **.cnf** solo.
- El sistema **solo** debe hacer algo si en el **arraylist** de `arrayArchivos` existe solamente la extensión **.pnd** SIN la existencia de las otras dos. En ese caso, solo en ese caso que me dispare un arteta que lo que hay en el `arrayArchivos` son solos archivos con extensión .pnd

Espero haber sido claro con lo que necesito, agradecería mucho su ayuda, desde ya gracias.

Comment: Te lanza algun error?

Comment: La idea es que lo desarrolles vos y que preguntes si te trabas en algún lado. La pregunta debería ser concreta sobre lo que te traba o no podés solucionar. Así como está planteado parece que querés que alguien te haga el trabajo.

Comment: No para nada! Es ahí donde estoy trabado estimado colega, plantie de esa forma la pregunta para que se entienda lo mejor posible, solo debo evaluar el contenido de dicho array y no se como hacer, e intentado con la propiedad **conteins** pero no me funciona.

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo con Einer, pero con afan de ayudar te puedo decir que para saber cuantas veces se presenta una extensión, una opción es insertar un valor en un mapa después de sumarle uno al contador. Al salir del for puedes evaluar el contenido del mapa y de esta forma sabes cuantas extensiones hay, es decir el número de objetos dentro del mapa te dice cuantas extensiones se encontraron.

Comment: Cuando dices **mapa**  que te refieres? Disculpa mi pregunta, a lo mejor es una burrada lo que pregunto pero no entendí esa parte.

Comment: @Einer el código que suministre arriba no me tira error, lo que necesito saber como evaluar el contenido del **ArrayList** e probado con la propiedad `contains` pero no logro el objetivo, por eso formule la pregunta, e probado varias cosas y no consigo dar con la indicada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Después de unos tres meses e terminado mi sistema y e logrado hacer lo que buscaba en esta pregunta, esta es la respuesta.

Lo que quería lograr era levantar los archivos existentes de una carpeta especificada e evaluar sus extensiones, para lo cual utilice 3 arraylist, en uno cargue todos los archivos con las extensiones que necesito(**.pnd**), en otro cargo los demás archivos con otras extensiones(**.cnf  .ana**) y en el tercer arraylist cargo únicamente los archivos únicos sin repetir sus nombres con extensiones **.pnd** únicas, **ya que dentro de la carpeta especificada puede a ver dos o mas archivos con el mismo nombre pero con distinta extensiones.** Si esta condición se cumple no agregaría al tercer arraylist el cual contendría archivos **.pnd** únicos. Hice lo siguiente.

Devlaramos los tres arraylist

```
ArrayList<String> arrayArchivosPnd = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> arrayArchivosNoPnd = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> arrayArchivosPndUnicos = new ArrayList<>();
```

Cargamos el **arrayArchivosPnd** con el metodo **buscarArchivosPnd()**

```
private void buscarArchivosPnd(File ruta) {
//        Creo el vector que contendra todos los archivos de una ruta especificada.
            File[] archivo = ruta.listFiles();
//        Evaluo si la carpeta especificada contiene archivos.
            if (archivo != null) {
//            Recorro el vector el cual tiene almacenado la ruta del archivo a buscar.
                for (int i = 0; i < archivo.length; i++) {
//                Evaluo si el archivo o la ruta es una carpeta.
                    if (archivo[i].isDirectory()) {
//                    Le paso la nueva ruta de la carpeta si se cambia la ruta e busca nuevamente.
                        buscarArchivosPnd(archivo[i]);
                    } else {
//                    Evaluo el tipo de extension. 
                        if (archivo[i].getName().endsWith(".pnd")) {
                            arrayArchivosPnd.add(archivo[i].getName());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Luego cargamos el **arrayArchivosNoPnd** con el metodo **buscarArchivosNoPnd()**

```
private void buscarArchivosNoPnd(File ruta) {
//        Creo el vector que contendra todos los archivos de una ruta especificada.
            File[] archivo = ruta.listFiles();
//        Evaluo si la carpeta especificada contiene archivos.
            if (archivo != null) {
//            Recorro el vector el cual tiene almacenado la ruta del archivo a buscar.
                for (int i = 0; i < archivo.length; i++) {
//                Evaluo si el archivo o la ruta es una carpeta.
                    if (archivo[i].isDirectory()) {
//                    Le paso la nueva ruta de la carpeta si se cambia la ruta e busca nuevamente.
                        buscarArchivosNoPnd(archivo[i]);
                    } else {
//                    Evaluo el tipo de extencion. 
                        if (archivo[i].getName().endsWith(".ana") || archivo[i].getName().endsWith(".cnf")) {
                            arrayArchivosNoPnd.add(archivo[i].getName());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Aquí buscamos los archivos únicos que existan en los dos arraylist cargados previamente, si cumplen la condición de que no se repitan llenamos el tercer array

```
public void buscarArchivosPndUnicos(File ruta) {
//            Por cada vuelta que da el bugle vaciamos los tres arraylist para que no se conviertan en acumuladores.
            this.arrayArchivosPndUnicos.clear();
            this.arrayArchivosPnd.clear();
            this.arrayArchivosNoPnd.clear();
//            Instanciamos los dos metodos anteriores para evaluar la condicion, pasandole por parametro la ruta.
            this.buscarArchivosPnd(ruta);
            this.buscarArchivosNoPnd(ruta);
            for (int i = 0; i < this.arrayArchivosPnd.size(); i++) {
//                Si no existen en el arrayArchivosNoPnd un archivo con el mismo nombre que es pasado por parametro
//                en la posicion i del arrayArchivosPnd signidica que ese archivo es unico y se lo agrega al arrayArchivosPndUnicos.
                if (!this.existeEnLosNoPnd(this.arrayArchivosPnd.get(i))) {
                    arrayArchivosPndUnicos.add(this.arrayArchivosPnd.get(i));
                }
            }
        }
```

Método booleano que retorna verdadero si los archivos son iguales o falso en el caso que sean archivos únicos.

```
private boolean existeEnLosNoPnd(String nombreArchivoPnd) {
//            Se convierte a un arreglo de array el string recibido.
            String[] arrayNombreExtensionPnd = nombreArchivoPnd.split(Pattern.quote("."));
            for (int i = 0; i < this.arrayArchivosNoPnd.size(); i++) {
//                Se recorre el arrayArchivosNoPnd y se lo convierte en un arreglo de array.
                String[] arrayNombreExtensionNoPnd = this.arrayArchivosNoPnd.get(i).split(Pattern.quote("."));
//                Se comparan los dos arreglos, si son iguales significa que los archivos son iguales.
                if (arrayNombreExtensionPnd[0].trim().equals(arrayNombreExtensionNoPnd[0].trim())) {
//                System.out.println("son iguales");                
                    return true;
                }
            }
//        System.out.println("es un pnd único");        
            return false;
        }
```

Espero que a alguien le sea útil, gracias.

Comment: Saludos Gerardo. Has realizado dos preguntas diferentes ([1](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/95237/250) y [2](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/94224/250)) y luego has respondido con el mismo texto a las dos. Si es la misma respuesta en ambos casos, entonces deberías plantearte marcar una de las preguntas como duplicada de la otra. Si no son la misma pregunta, entonces quizás deberías cambiar las respuestas para que se ajusten al caso específico de cada pregunta. Te recomiendo leer [ask] en el centro de ayuda.