# Agregar archivos entre dos ArrayList en Java

Tags: java, arraylist, timer

Mi pregunta es, se puede recorrer dos `ArrayList<String>` haciendo que ambos se cargue con un bucle `for` ejecutandoce por un par de mili segundos 
disparado con un `timer` y que ese primer `ArrayList` pierda el foco y recorrer el segundo `ArrayList<String>` haciendo que el primero se vacié completamente en java?

Es decir, que vayan alternando la carga de archivos. Por ejemplo, tengo el `array1` se carga por unos mili segundos con un `timer`, luego cargar el otro `array2` haciendo que el `array1` se vacié y así sucesivamente de esa forma pudiendo tener siempre archivos nuevos y distintos.

¿Porque necesito esto?

Tengo un método que busca archivos y evalúa los tipos de extensiones que hay dentro de una carpeta especifica la cual se agregan y eliminan archivos constantemente, pero el método que tengo se agregan a un `ArrayList`, dentro de ese arreglo, se van agregando archivos constantemente cada 5 segundos, sin ser eliminados, solo agrega, pero dentro de ese método `buscarArchivos()`, tengo una condición que a veces se cumple porque quedan archivos viejos almacenados en el `ArrayList`:

```
public void buscarArchivo(File ruta) {

           private int contador = 0;
           ArrayList<String> arrayArchivos = new ArrayList<>();

//        Creo el vector que contendra todos los archivos de una ruta especificada.
        File[] archivo = ruta.listFiles();
//        Evaluo si la carpeta especificada contiene archivos.
        if (archivo != null) {
//            Recorro el vector el cual tiene almacenado la ruta del archivo a buscar.
            for (int i = 0; i < archivo.length; i++) {
//                Evaluo si el archivo o la ruta es una carpeta.
                if (archivo[i].isDirectory()) {
//                    Le paso la nueva ruta de la carpeta si se cambia la ruta e busca nuevamente.
                    buscarArchivo(archivo[i]);
                } else {
//                    Evaluo el tipo de extencion. 
                    if (archivo[i].getName().endsWith(".pnd") || archivo[i].getName().endsWith(".ana") || archivo[i].getName().endsWith(".cnf")) {
                        contador++;
                        arrayArchivos.add(archivo[i].getName());
                        evaluarArchivos();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void evaluarArchivos() {
                String pnd = "pnd";
                String ana = "ana";
                String cnf = "cnf";
        boolean existePnd = false,
                existeAna = false,
                existeCnf = false;

        for (String archivo : arrayArchivos) {
//            El punto se usa en las expresiones regulares por lo que si se desea usar como tal se debe definir con "\\"
                String[] palabras = archivo.split("\\.");
//                Se comvierte el arreglo a un string pandole la longitud completa del arrglo.
                String ext = palabras[palabras.length - 1];
//                Evaluo si es pnd
                if (ext.equals(pnd)) {
                    existePnd = true;
                }
//                Evaluo si es ana
                if (ext.equals(ana)) {
                    existeAna = true;
                }
//                Evaluo si es cnf
                if (ext.equals(cnf)) {
                    existeCnf = true;
                }
            }
//            Pregunto si existe pnd y no ana y no cnf.
            if (existePnd && (!existeAna && !existeCnf)) {
                //Codigo si solo existen archivos .pnd
                System.out.println("Alerta");
            }
    }
```

Como verán el código busca por extenciones de archivos, como la carpeta en la que hago la búsqueda se agregan y eliminan constantemente archivos con esas extensiones, haciendo que mi condición SOLO se cumpla si cuando arranca el `timer` se encuentran extensiones de tipo **.pnd** de la carpeta, si se agregan algunas de las demás extensiones también se cumple, PERO si las extensiones **.ana** y **.cnf** desaparecen dentro de la carpeta mi condición no se cumple porque dentro del `ArrayList` existen esas extensiones almacenadas y lo que necesito es saber si hay algún modo de alternar la carga entre dos arreglos o de vaciar el mismo pudiendo tener dentro del mismo siempre archivos distintos, me explico?

Es decir, cargar un `Array` evaluar contenido, cargar otro `Array` con archivos nuevos agregados a la carpeta y vaciar el anterior.

Comment: Lo que entendí es que tu no necesitas una lista propiamente dicha, utiliza algo concurrente (un ArrayList no permite iterar y eliminar a la vez) te recomiendo utilizar un BlockingDeque ese añadiría en tu hilo principal más datos y el Timer (hilo secundario) eliminaría.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingDeque.html

Comment: @Gerardo Ferreya, De acuerdo a los que menciona, ¿usted realiza un procedimiento especifico si en algún directorio o subdirectorio solo existen archivos con extension ".pnd", en un instante de tiempo? ¿Cada cuanto tiene que hacer esta validación? ¿los archivos que se hayan borrado del directorio físico (disco), no deben tenerse encuenta en la siguiente validación?

Comment: En adición al comentario de @Ajeno, y en tono más general, lo que describes como "en unos milisegundos se carga uno, en otros milisegundos se carga otro" es una descripción de programación concurrente, con distintos *threads* corriendo "en paralelo" a la vez. Te recomiendo que busques algún curso/tutorial al respecto para tomar una idea de lo que se puede hacer y como se puede hacer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de unos tres meses e terminado mi sistema y e logrado hacer lo que buscaba en esta pregunta, esta es la respuesta.

Lo que quería lograr era levantar los archivos existentes de una carpeta especificada e evaluar sus extensiones, para lo cual utilice 3 arraylist, en uno cargue todos los archivos con las extensiones que necesito(**.pnd**), en otro cargo los demás archivos con otras extensiones(**.cnf  .ana**) y en el tercer arraylist cargo únicamente los archivos únicos sin repetir sus nombres con extensiones **.pnd** únicas, **ya que dentro de la carpeta especificada puede a ver dos o mas archivos con el mismo nombre pero con distinta extensiones.** Si esta condición se cumple no agregaría al tercer arraylist el cual contendría archivos **.pnd** únicos. Hice lo siguiente.

Devlaramos los tres arraylist

```
ArrayList<String> arrayArchivosPnd = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> arrayArchivosNoPnd = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> arrayArchivosPndUnicos = new ArrayList<>();
```

Cargamos el **arrayArchivosPnd** con el metodo **buscarArchivosPnd()**

```
private void buscarArchivosPnd(File ruta) {
//        Creo el vector que contendra todos los archivos de una ruta especificada.
            File[] archivo = ruta.listFiles();
//        Evaluo si la carpeta especificada contiene archivos.
            if (archivo != null) {
//            Recorro el vector el cual tiene almacenado la ruta del archivo a buscar.
                for (int i = 0; i < archivo.length; i++) {
//                Evaluo si el archivo o la ruta es una carpeta.
                    if (archivo[i].isDirectory()) {
//                    Le paso la nueva ruta de la carpeta si se cambia la ruta e busca nuevamente.
                        buscarArchivosPnd(archivo[i]);
                    } else {
//                    Evaluo el tipo de extension. 
                        if (archivo[i].getName().endsWith(".pnd")) {
                            arrayArchivosPnd.add(archivo[i].getName());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Luego cargamos el **arrayArchivosNoPnd** con el metodo **buscarArchivosNoPnd()**

```
private void buscarArchivosNoPnd(File ruta) {
//        Creo el vector que contendra todos los archivos de una ruta especificada.
            File[] archivo = ruta.listFiles();
//        Evaluo si la carpeta especificada contiene archivos.
            if (archivo != null) {
//            Recorro el vector el cual tiene almacenado la ruta del archivo a buscar.
                for (int i = 0; i < archivo.length; i++) {
//                Evaluo si el archivo o la ruta es una carpeta.
                    if (archivo[i].isDirectory()) {
//                    Le paso la nueva ruta de la carpeta si se cambia la ruta e busca nuevamente.
                        buscarArchivosNoPnd(archivo[i]);
                    } else {
//                    Evaluo el tipo de extencion. 
                        if (archivo[i].getName().endsWith(".ana") || archivo[i].getName().endsWith(".cnf")) {
                            arrayArchivosNoPnd.add(archivo[i].getName());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Aquí buscamos los archivos únicos que existan en los dos arraylist cargados previamente, si cumplen la condición de que no se repitan llenamos el tercer array

```
public void buscarArchivosPndUnicos(File ruta) {
//            Por cada vuelta que da el bugle vaciamos los tres arraylist para que no se conviertan en acumuladores.
            this.arrayArchivosPndUnicos.clear();
            this.arrayArchivosPnd.clear();
            this.arrayArchivosNoPnd.clear();
//            Instanciamos los dos metodos anteriores para evaluar la condicion, pasandole por parametro la ruta.
            this.buscarArchivosPnd(ruta);
            this.buscarArchivosNoPnd(ruta);
            for (int i = 0; i < this.arrayArchivosPnd.size(); i++) {
//                Si no existen en el arrayArchivosNoPnd un archivo con el mismo nombre que es pasado por parametro
//                en la posicion i del arrayArchivosPnd signidica que ese archivo es unico y se lo agrega al arrayArchivosPndUnicos.
                if (!this.existeEnLosNoPnd(this.arrayArchivosPnd.get(i))) {
                    arrayArchivosPndUnicos.add(this.arrayArchivosPnd.get(i));
                }
            }
        }
```

Método booleano que retorna verdadero si los archivos son iguales o falso en el caso que sean archivos únicos.

```
private boolean existeEnLosNoPnd(String nombreArchivoPnd) {
//            Se convierte a un arreglo de array el string recibido.
            String[] arrayNombreExtensionPnd = nombreArchivoPnd.split(Pattern.quote("."));
            for (int i = 0; i < this.arrayArchivosNoPnd.size(); i++) {
//                Se recorre el arrayArchivosNoPnd y se lo convierte en un arreglo de array.
                String[] arrayNombreExtensionNoPnd = this.arrayArchivosNoPnd.get(i).split(Pattern.quote("."));
//                Se comparan los dos arreglos, si son iguales significa que los archivos son iguales.
                if (arrayNombreExtensionPnd[0].trim().equals(arrayNombreExtensionNoPnd[0].trim())) {
//                System.out.println("son iguales");                
                    return true;
                }
            }
//        System.out.println("es un pnd único");        
            return false;
        }
```

Espero que a alguien le sea útil, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

creo que tengo una solucion alternativa, no creo que sea necesario utilizar Timers, simplemente utiliza números aleatorios, la solucion se resume en 3 pasos:

1. Obtener número de elementos del primer arreglo
2. Obtener número de elemento del segundo arreglo
3. Llenar ambos arreglos

debería quedar algo parecido a esto

```
ArrayList<String> archivos = getArchivos();
Random rn = new Random();

//obtener el numero de elementos a almacenar
int max1 = archivos.size()  + 1;
int elementos1 = rn.nextInt(max1);
int elementos2 = archivos.size() - elementos1;
List<String> archivos1 = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> archivos2 = new ArrayList<>();

//Llenamos el primer arrayList aleatoriamente
for(int i=0; i<elementos1; i++){
    Random r = new Random();
    //obtener el elemento aleatorio a ingresar en el arreglo
    int max = archivos.size() + 1;
    int randomNum =  rn.nextInt(max);

    //Obtenemos el elemento, lo agregamos a la nueva lista y
    //lo borramos de la original
    String archivo = archivos.get(randomNum);
    archivos1.add(archivo);
    archivos.remove(randomNum);
}

//Lo mismo va para el segundo
for(int i=0; i<elementos2; i++){
    Random r = new Random();
    int max = archivos.size() + 1;
    int randomNum =  rn.nextInt(max);
    String archivo = archivos.get(randomNum);
    archivos2.add(archivo);
    archivos.remove(randomNum);
}
```

Si quieres mantener la lista original solo falta hacer una copia temporal para hacer el proceso que te comentaba